# Given 2 Random Variables, Please fill out the table

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am working on a problem and I have no clue where to start.
[image: Here is the problem]

I'm not sure what It is asking, or where to start.

If you guys could give me the steps to take, show me what concepts are used, or a link to somewhere helpful I would appreciate it!

I am lost so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That table is a joint probability distribution table for $X$ and $Y$. For example, the first empty box has $P(X=1 \cap Y=1)$.

I'll give two methods to calculate all the joint probabilities. The first a more obvious method and the second perhaps a more intuitive method.

**Solution $1$**

We mostly use the formula definition for conditional probability in various ways, which is: for events $A,B$, if $P(B) \neq 0$,

$$P(A \mid B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

Firstly,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y=1) &=& \sum_{k=1}^3{P(Y=1\vert X=k)P(X=k)} \qquad\qquad\text{(by Law of Total Probability)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{3}{5}\left(P(X=1) + P(X=2) + P(X=3)\right) = \dfrac{3}{5}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We can use that to get three of the six required values,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X=1 \cap Y=1) &=& P(X=1\mid Y=1)P(Y=1) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{10}. \\
&&\\
P(X=2 \cap Y=1) &=& P(X=2\mid Y=1)P(Y=1) = \frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{10}. \\
&&\\
P(X=3 \cap Y=1) &=& P(X=3\mid Y=1)P(Y=1) = \frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{3}{5} = \frac{3}{10}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Next,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X=1) &=& \dfrac{P(X=1\cap Y=1)}{P(Y=1\mid X=1)} = \dfrac{1/10}{3/5} = \frac{1}{6}. \\
&&\\
P(X=2) &=& \dfrac{P(X=2\cap Y=1)}{P(Y=1\mid X=2)} = \dfrac{2/10}{3/5} = \frac{2}{6}. \\
&&\\
P(X=3) &=& \dfrac{P(X=3\cap Y=1)}{P(Y=1\mid X=3)} = \dfrac{3/10}{3/5} = \frac{3}{6}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y=2\mid X=1) &=& 1-P(Y=1\text{ or }3\mid X=1) = 1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}. \\
&&\\
P(Y=3\mid X=2) &=& 1-P(Y=1\text{ or }2\mid X=2) = 1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}. \\
&&\\
P(Y=2\mid X=3) &=& 1-P(Y=1\text{ or }3\mid X=3) = 1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

We can now calculate the last three required probabilities.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X=1\cap Y=2) &=& P(Y=2\mid X=1)P(X=1) = \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{15}. \\
&&\\
P(X=2\cap Y=3) &=& P(Y=3\mid X=2)P(X=2) = \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{6} = \frac{2}{15}. \\
&&\\
P(X=3\cap Y=2) &=& P(Y=2\mid X=3)P(X=3) = \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{6} = \frac{3}{15}. \\
&&\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Y & X=1 & X=2 & X=3 \\
\hline
1 & 1/10 & 2/10 & 3/10 \\
2 & 1/15 & 0 & 3/15 \\
3 & 0 & 2/15 & 0
\end{array}
$$

**Solution $2$**

Note that

$$\dfrac{P(X=i \mid Y=k)}{P(X=j \mid Y=k)} = \dfrac{P(X=i \cap Y=k)P(Y=k)}{P(X=j \cap Y=k)P(Y=k)} = \dfrac{P(X=i \cap Y=k)}{P(X=j \cap Y=k)}.$$

We see that the ratio of conditional probabilities equals the ratio of the corresponding joint probabilities.

In the first column we see that,
$$P(Y=2\mid X=1) = 1-P(Y=1\text{ or }3\mid X=1) = 1-\frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}.$$ Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y=1\cap X=1) : P(Y=2\cap X=1) &=& P(Y=1\mid X=1) : P(Y=2\mid X=1) \\
&=& \frac{3}{5} : \frac{2}{5} = 3 : 2.
\end{eqnarray*}

So, for some $r \gt 0$, we must have
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Y & X=1 & X=2 & X=3 \\
\hline
1 & 3r & ? & ? \\
2 & 2r & 0 & ? \\
3 & 0 & ? & 0
\end{array}
$$

Working now in the $Y=1$ row,

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& P(X=1\cap Y=1) : P(X=2\cap Y=1) : P(X=3\cap Y=1) \\
&&\qquad \qquad \qquad = P(X=1\mid Y=1) : P(X=2\mid Y=1) : P(X=3\mid Y=1) \\
&&\qquad \qquad \qquad = \frac{1}{6} : \frac{2}{6} : \frac{3}{6} \\
&&\qquad \qquad \qquad = 1:2:3. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

So now we have,
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Y & X=1 & X=2 & X=3 \\
\hline
1 & 3r & 6r & 9r \\
2 & 2r & 0 & ? \\
3 & 0 & ? & 0
\end{array}
$$

Working in the remaining columns as we did in the $X=1$ column, we can fill in the last two ? boxes:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Y & X=1 & X=2 & X=3 \\
\hline
1 & 3r & 6r & 9r \\
2 & 2r & 0 & 6r \\
3 & 0 & 4r & 0
\end{array}
$$

We know all the probabilities in the table must add to $1$, so we have $30r=1$ and so $r=1/30$. Finally, we can complete the table (the same as Solution $1$):
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Y & X=1 & X=2 & X=3 \\
\hline
1 & 1/10 & 2/10 & 3/10 \\
2 & 1/15 & 0 & 3/15 \\
3 & 0 & 2/15 & 0
\end{array}
$$